# How do I select one among the duplicate records and non-duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table like below

```
var1        var2        var3        ra
a           a           a           1
b           a           a           2
c           a           a           3
d           b           b           4
e           c           c           1
```

Duplicate records are identified based on `columns var2 and var 3`. last column is the row number for duplicates. I need to select only maximum row-numbered records in duplicate records and other non duplicate records.

The expected output will be

```
var2        var3        ra
a           a           3
b           b           4
c           c           1
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want `var1`, try:

```
select var2, var3, max(ra)
from myTable
group by var2, var3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *do* need to pull in other columns (the existing answers give the exact output you've specified), you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH OrderedRows as (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var2,var3 ORDER BY ra desc) as rn
    FROM <Table>
)
SELECT
    * --TODO - Explicit column list
FROM
    OrderedRows
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select var2, var3, max(ra)
from table1
group by var2, var3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select var2, var3, max(ra) as ra
from tableX
group by var2, var3
```